# tbats forecasts negative values

Tags: r, forecasting, tbats

I am forecasting monthly data with `tbats`. I want to forecast only positive or null data. However, using the `log` transformation with `lambda=0` still gives negative forecasts.
My data are from January 2014 to September 2016 and I am forecasting the next 12 months.

```
V1  Month
41.86956521739131   janvier-14
42.85000000000001   février-14
44.09523809523812   mars-14
36.45454545454546   avril-14
35.000000000000014  mai-14
38.76190476190476   juin-14
47.91304347826087   juillet-14
40.28571428571429   août-14
32.45454545454545   septembre-14
36.43478260869565   octobre-14
34.05   novembre-14
29.695652173913043  décembre-14
26.409090909090914  janvier-15
28.349999999999998  février-15
22.863636363636363  mars-15
28.863636363636363  avril-15
30.09523809523809   mai-15
31.181818181818187  juin-15
38.173913043478265  juillet-15
43.666666666666664  août-15
23.04545454545455   septembre-15
13.045454545454545  octobre-15
19.57142857142857   novembre-15
11.82608695652174   décembre-15
11.380952380952381  janvier-16
17.238095238095237  février-16
15.478260869565217  mars-16
9.142857142857142   avril-16
4.363636363636363   mai-16
4.590909090909091   juin-16
11.666666666666668  juillet-16
14.0    août-16
13.5    septembre-16
1.87744673313407    octobre-16
-0.16414435236140235    novembre-16
-1.4557653079641784 décembre-16
-2.518701279594417  janvier-17
-1.1818033573924136 février-17
-0.42374354964241134    mars-17
-3.945367059520266  avril-17
-6.8719451365439275 mai-17
-2.565307285050311  juin-17
4.3693087467099065  juillet-17
3.777567990467044   août-17
-4.218520709733794  septembre-17
```

R code :

```
library(forecast)
data_ts <- ts("V1", start=c(2014,01), frequency=12)
fit <- tbats(data_ts, lambda=0)
forecast_series <- forecast(fit, 12)
```

How can I constraint the model to forecast only positive values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tbats` does not let you choose your own Box-Cox transformation parameter. The `lambda` argument will be ignored.

You appear to have added the forecasts to the end of the data. So I will ignore the values after September 2016.

Then you can force a transformation explicitly like this:

```
x <- log(window(data_ts, end=c(2016,9)))
fit <- tbats(x, use.box.cox=FALSE)
fit$lambda <- 0
fit$control$use.box.cox <- TRUE
fc <- forecast(fit)
fc$x <- exp(x)
plot(fc)
```

It's a little messy because that is not how `tbats` is intended to be used.

Comment: The log transformation works (no more negative values) but now the forecast is not good: there is the same value predicted for the next 12 months, 13.557 (the last known value). Is it because there is not enough history?

Comment: See http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/flat-forecasts/

Comment: I know this is very old but it should be

    ```fc$x <- exp(fc$x)```

right?

Comment: Either will work. `x` is the data and it is stored within `fc` as component `x`.